# Update data in Arabic Language

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I would like to Update Arabic data in database.
I tried with below code with static data,it is working fine

```
Update db.Country SET (ColumnName)=N'الصين' WHERE ID=1
```

but now I would like to do it in a dynamic way, so I have taken a parameter
@ArCountryName I declared the variable as NVarchar(Max) so by doing this I thought there is no need to add the N before the parameter, but if I do so the values are not being updated in a correct way.. It is storing question marks into the database

So, How can I add the prefix N for a parameter like @ArCountryName to get the required output

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry this is working fine if I am declaring parameter as NVarchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring the parameter as `nvarchar` should solve your problem.

```
declare @ArCountryName nvarchar(3000)
```

Comment: He might not see or verify whether he has given Nvarchar, for this issue declaring the Nvarchar should solve the issue that's why I have given the answer like that @FactorMystic . I think this deserve a down vote

Comment: He has to declare the parameter also as Nvarchar